# "'userArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Specified Resource is not reachable in this region" when requesting quicksight embed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am attempting to embed a Quicksight dashboard in a web-app and have been using this [amazon-quicksight-embedding-sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sample)  to get up and running. I followed all the instruction in the README and have the code running in my AWS lambda function.
When I test the code it returns null and the logs report the ValidationException in the title. The expected output is a URL for embedding the dashboard in a webpage.
Actual output is as follows:

```
ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:iam::655956663811:user/admin' at 'userArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-2')
at Object.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
```

The user 'Admin' is an IAM user with Administrator Access and the quicksight account has whitelisted embedding for amazonaws.com and amazon.com.
The test input for the lambda is:

```
{
"dashboardId": "311d89d1-d666-4fb1-91cf-1500e28b76ca",
"userArn": "arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:user/admin",
"apiGatewayUrl": "bypassed for lambda testing",
"resetDisabled": "false",
"undoRedoDisabled": "false"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Try like this:

aws quicksight describe-user --user-name  --aws-account-id <account_id>  --namespace default --region

And then use Arn from this response.

Comment: --user-name=<username> must be one of the managed user created in the QuickSight management dashboard